# Add icon on video.js play bar

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I'm using video.js framework. I have videos and built-in questions which popup while playing video, for example on 10th second. How can I manage to add some icon note on 10th second showing that there is question expected, like on the photo below?

[image]

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [videojs-markers](https://github.com/spchuang/videojs-markers) plugin may be close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I needed